# How do I avoid 404 error in deployed react app when I refresh page?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to deploy react app on `Netflify` and it was okay before I deployed.
However, since i deployed this app, whenever i refresh it didn't get the same `URL`,and it returns the 404 page on Netflify.  so i tried to find it but i couldn't get how to do, and I deployed it only client side. I have no idea how to fix it without server side.
So How do i avoid this issue??

And I searched to fix but it didn't work for some reason.

This is what i tried :
[image]
I added netlify.toml file in src folder and

```js
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/"
  status = 200
```

I wrote this in the file.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: add hashrouter in your react app index.js. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another method you could possibly try is to add a `_redirects` file inside your `/public` folder.**

And then parse this into that file:

```
/*  /index.html  200
```

Deploy your app, and netify will check for that file, with any URL it returns to index.html with code 200

Detail explaination [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify).